# Regex for incrementing a number in Sublime Text 2

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

So I've seeded my DB with some ID's using `artisan` new `db:seed`, but now I need to increment all ID's by 1. I know how to find a number, but I can't figure out how to increment it in the replace box (if it is possible).

```
<?php
return array(
      array("title"=>'Paris',
        "country_id"=>0),
      array("title"=>'Lion',
        "country_id"=>0),
      array("title"=>'Nice',
        "country_id"=>0),
      array("title"=>'Nantes',
        "country_id"=>0),
      array("title"=>'Bordeaux',
        "country_id"=>0),
      array("title"=>'Montpellier',
        "country_id"=>0),
      array("title"=>'Berlin',
        "country_id"=>1),
         array("title"=>'Halle',
        "country_id"=>1),
           array("title"=>'Leipzig',
        "country_id"=>1),
             array("title"=>'Dredsen',
        "country_id"=>1),
     array("title"=>'Hamburg',
        "country_id"=>1),
     array("title"=>'Altona',
        "country_id"=>1),
      array("title"=>'Rome',
        "country_id"=>2),
      array("title"=>'Verona',
        "country_id"=>2),
      array("title"=>'Venice',
        "country_id"=>2),
      array("title"=>'Milan',
        "country_id"=>2),
      array("title"=>'Naples',
        "country_id"=>2),
      array("title"=>'Turin',
        "country_id"=>2),
        array("title"=>'Luzern',
        "country_id"=>3),
         array("title"=>'Zurich',
        "country_id"=>3),
          array("title"=>'Berne',
        "country_id"=>3),
           array("title"=>'Geneva',
        "country_id"=>3),
            array("title"=>'Basel',
        "country_id"=>3),
             array("title"=>'Lugano',
        "country_id"=>3)
    );
```

Comment: Could you post the text that you want to increment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tested this using the [Emmet sublime plugin](https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime#available-actions).

Once installed, search for `\d` with Regular Expressions enabled, and then simply hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> to increment all selected numbers by one.

Comment: Great. On a Mac this combination is already taken for floating windows around, so one should go to the key bindings and change it (i used super(cmd)+uparrow)